# How do questions marked community wiki AFTER you answer impact rep upon recalc

Tags: discussion, reputation, community-wiki, reputation-recalc

I did a search, and checked the FAQ, and checked out the questions which came up as related from the title, and still have nothing on this. But if this is a dupe, please close it and point me at the right question. :) (I say this because it feels like it SHOULD be a dupe; I just couldn't find it.)

There's been talk on Meta about rep recalcs, when they're done, etc. What I'm curious about is what happens if you have an answer which was not marked community wiki, realized it should have been (IE, your rep was going up and you couldn't explain it), and you went and marked it wiki, and THEN, a recalc was performed.

I got to thinking about this because I hopped on SO tonight, and I'll admit to being something of a semi-lurker there recently, but my rep feels high. Not TOO high, but high. And I remembered [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213508/why-do-personal-software-projects-fail-i-e-projects-with-the-goal-of-leading-t/213531#213531).

At the time, I guess the question hadn't been wiki-fied. I answered, not realizing that. I recall marking it wiki myself after noticing my rep increasing inexplicably. (However, I don't see that in the edit history; in the edit history it looks like Community marked it as a wiki answer.)

Anyway, if/when my SO rep is recalculated, will I lose the rep I gained on that answer? I feel I should -- it should have ALWAYS been wiki (in fact the whole question should have been). But I'm curious as to how the implementation detail works out.

BTW, if possible, please refrain from pointing out the irony that I also asked [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5329/are-we-too-rep-focused). :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Community Wiki is a date field, as you can see yourself in the cc-wiki dumps.

- Votes prior to the date count towards rep.
- Votes after the date do not.

Comment: Official word = accepted answer!

Comment: @John: Shouldn't your assignment be reversed?

Answer (score 1):

They do not. If you answer a question and it is not marked as CW, it's not auto-converted once the question is made into a wiki.

If the OP did not make it a wiki, you are left to your discretion as to whether or not to mark your answer a wiki. All rep earned before the post becomes a wiki will stay there, even after rep recalcs.

Comment: If a mod converts a question over to CW it converts all the answers to CW as well automatically. It is also likely that any answer that is marked as CW this way (or switched over at some point) would lose the rep points it may have accumulated during the time it was not CW after a recalc. I can't be sure of this and one would either have to have solid facts from Atwood or another dev, or test it out on themselves.

Comment: @TXI: I always forget about you mods and your ubertools. Good nugget of info, though.