# What happens to old vote points when a question becomes community wiki?

Tags: discussion, reputation, community-wiki

Do reputation points earned on a question or an answer get taken away when that question becomes a community wiki?

When a question becomes community wiki, can reputation points still be awarded to answers?

I saw a question that was community wiki because (I think) it was edited 4 times by the original question author.  So... does my prior answer to him not win me anything any more?

Comment: Dupe-asauraus: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16750

Comment: @Eric: I'm not convinced this is a dupe. I think this question is a refinement or complement of my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you answer a question that was not community wiki, you earn rep as normal.

If the question becomes community wiki, your answer will stay in its normal state and still gain or lose reputation.

If your answer is flipped over to CW, you will not lose any previous earned rep, but you will be prevented from earning or losing further rep on that answer.

On a recalculation, I am not certain what would happen with something that gets flipped over.

Comment: What is a recalculation?

Comment: A recalc is triggered either by a mod or by an automatic system function. It will basically recalculate your reputation based upon what questions and answers are available. Example, if you gained rep on a question that was later deleted, your new rep score would not reflect any scores gained on that deleted item.

Comment: Existing (pre-flip) reputation is retained. No post-flip rep is gained.

Answer (score 8):

Community Wiki is a date field, as you can see yourself in the cc-wiki dumps.

- Votes prior to the date count towards rep.
- Votes after the date do not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you get to keep your acquired rep post-conversion. I'm more interested in what happens upon a recalc, if you keep the rep points that came from what ultimately ended up as a cw-post.

Comment: That makes two of us! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16750