# If I change a question to a wiki after the fact will I lose the points I've gotten for it?

Tags: support, reputation, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens to old vote points when a question becomes community wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16762/what-happens-to-old-vote-points-when-a-question-becomes-community-wiki)

I think the title says it all for this one.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16762/what-happens-to-old-vote-points-when-a-question-becomes-community-wiki.

Answer (score 2):

[No, not even with a recalc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16762/what-happens-to-old-vote-points-when-a-question-becomes-community-wiki).

There is actually a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31902/remove-reputation-gained-from-questions-and-answers-turned-community-wiki) to change this behavior.