# What happens to rep when an answer converted to a community wiki is deleted?

Tags: support, community-wiki

Suppose we have the following scenario:

1. Question is posted
2. I answer question and gain rep from upvotes
3. Question converted to community wiki, causing my answer to be converted to a community wiki
4. My community wiki answer is deleted

According to [How do questions marked community wiki AFTER you answer impact rep upon recalc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16750/how-do-questions-marked-community-wiki-after-you-answer-impact-rep-upon-recalc), votes before conversion to community wiki count toward my rep, but votes after the conversion don't count toward my rep.

But based on [If your answer is unaccepted after becoming Community Wiki, do you still lose 15 rep for it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96675/133027), it sounds like a rep recalc will result in lost rep if my answer was accepted before the question and answer were wikified, then un-accepted after they were wikified. (Edit: apparently [recalcs are a thing of the past](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/).)

If the answer is *deleted* after it is wikified, do I still keep the rep gained prior to wikification, or do I lose it? (and vise-versa, if I lost rep rather than gaining it prior to wikification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community Wiki isn't really relevant here - when a post is deleted, all the reputation points it gave its author is being removed, unless the post is considered "Worthwhile" i.e. score of 3 or greater and visible on the site for at least 60 days as explained [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/), in which case the reputation is preserved.

As far as I can tell, the Community Wiki status is being checked when a vote is cast: if the post on which the vote was cast is Community Wiki, the vote will have no effect on reputation, and somewhere behind the scenes, there will be a "0" recorded as "net effect on reputation due to this vote" - then when the vote is being "nullified" e.g. undone by the user who cast it, post deleted, user removed etc - that "net change" is the thing that will affect the reputation - the recalc does not check if the post was CW by the time the vote was cast. (*I might be wrong on this, but based on my experience and my common sense - I believe it's correct*)

Comment: Thanks! The first time I read this, your leading statement that CW isn't relevant threw me off, but after rereading I understand that when a post is deleted, the rep it gave its author will be removed, regardless of whether it was converted to a CW--so any rep earned before it was converted will be deleted. And the only exception is that the rep will be preserved if it was "worthwhile" according to the terms you outlined.

Comment: @Rob that's right, glad you came to understand that. :)