# Why does my reputation decrease if I downvote another post?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Hi,

I am wondering why do my reputation points go down if I downvote someone else's post?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15863/why-do-you-lose-reputation-for-down-voting (and I'm safe comment can't be down voted ;-) also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments is related

Comment: I've been using StackExchange sites for a lot of years and only now I learn that downvoting makes the downvoter lose 1 point. I haven't downvoted many answers, but anyway I guess should have RTFM before :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do you lose reputation for downvoting answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15863/why-do-you-lose-reputation-for-downvoting-answers)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

This happens because your down vote will remove 2 rep from that user. You lose 1 rep as well to prevent you from gaming the system. We couldn't let you go around taking rep away from others without making you consider if it's really worth it, could we?

If you can't justify the small loss to express your opinion on the particular post, then there's no need to down vote. If other people feel more strongly than you, they'll take care of it.

Comment: This is a wonderfully great idea. Doing it this way keeps a general atmosphere of 'positiveness' alive throughout the site, whereas truly horrible answers go negative. nice one SO.

Comment: I don't know if I agree. If an answer clearly is not related to the OP's ? or is wrong, it should get a down vote. Why punish the person when they are doing the right thing? Also are people really dishonest enough to just go around down voting stuff? Couldn't such behavior be detected and then the user be warned/banned as a result?

Comment: If more number of people are downvoting a question, then it should be good if the reputations are awarded back.

Comment: I wish i could upvote Arun A K's comment to a million.

Comment: I agree that if enough people downvote an answer then the -1 rep should be awarded back. This isn't a big deal to established users, but this discourages newbies from voting something down.

Comment: Thank god Comment does not have down-vote. Otherwise it should also punish the user.

Comment: I do not agree! In the long run this would facilitate the herd behavior to take place. I would not downvote any post from now on.

Comment: This is not a game between asker and down voter. It should have a purpose of protecting down voting points of other users when is not necessary (like anti-fraud). So, in my opinion it should not decrease point from down voter at certain conditions as like it is not a fraud.

Comment: @ArunAK, when that user removes their post your reputation is rewarded back, which is nearly the same.

Comment: @ArunAK I consider it more fair for the downvoter to lose 2 points and the owner of the post to lose one point. Once downvoted, it is difficult to recover if the subject is special hence less audience visits it. In such cases it is not rare for a downvote to be the result of a downvoter's incompetence on the subject.

Comment: So, what is the point of earning down-vote privilege. It's contradictory. It trusts me after that min reputation (to downvote) or it still doesn't trust me?

Comment: Or better, increase the reputation required to down-vote.

Comment: is it always -1 rep ?

Comment: I've come across a question with 350+ upvotes, and 3 answers with flat out incorrect content. None of the incorrect answers had downvotes, I'm guessing cause no-one wanted to loose rep until I came along.

Comment: I lost a point for down-voting a question posted as an answer that was essentially "I'm having this problem too, did you find an answer?"  Getting closer to only searching for answers if I don't find them elsewhere on the web; at this point I'm done participating.

Comment: When you upvote, you give them 10 reps. When you downvote you reduce 2 of theirs and 1 of yours. This is slightly disproportionate. A more proportionate system would be downvote reduces 10 of theirs and 1 of yours, or 2 of theirs and 0.2 of yours.

Comment: Yesterday I downvoted an answer that was so outlandish it was a severe disservice to the community. As a result I lost my own karma. I will never ever downvote again, the site can keep their occasional awful answers. It's like one is charged a fee because they picked up some trash from the park.

Comment: @AlessioSangalli `It's like one is charged a fee because they picked up some trash from the park.` I agree ,Damn true

Comment: @AlessioSangalli This is the same feeling I get. Sometimes answers are outdated and not correct anymore and those answers have a lot of points. The most recent and correct answers are then below. Nobody seems to be downvoting because of the rep loss. It's like nobody wants to clean up the place because it cost them rep.