# Down Voting deduct Reputation Point

Tags: support, reputation, voting, down-votes

This question is already asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15863/why-do-you-lose-reputation-for-down-voting) but it does not quite answer my question.

When I review, I get some posts that are answers of very poor quality, or I get flags declined on questions with the message **flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer.**

So posts should be down voted. But if the post belongs to other domains you are active in, such as .net, but the post actually is in PHP, then your Reputation Point will detect I got it from [**here**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15863/why-do-you-lose-reputation-for-down-voting).

My Question is: If a post is not good, then we should down vote. But if this post simply belongs to another category, a point should not be deducted. So why are Reputation Point deducted in this case?

Comment: The penalty has absolutely nothing to do with what tags there are on the question or what tags you're active in. The penalty is on downvoting answers and not questions, and among other things it is to discourage strategic downvoting (where you downvote all the other answers to a question you've downvoted).

Answer (score 6):

The deduction of one point is more a psychological thing to make you think twice before you downvote.

One point deduction shouldn't stop you from downvoting a bad post.

Answer (score 1):

> So post should be down voted but post belongs to other domain means you active in .net but post belong to php then your Reputation Point will detect I got from Here.

What? This makes no sense.

> My Question is if any post is not good we should down vote whether this post belong to any category and point should not deduct.

That's not a question

---

The downvote penalty is to prevent people from using downvotes to kill the competition. It's just 1 rep — if you're occasionally using it on wrong answers, that's good. It takes one answer upvote to offset 10 downvotes from you, so it's not a great loss.

Comment on the answer and explain why it is wrong. There's a chance the answerer will fix it, or will delete it altogether (both cases give you a chance to get your rep back).

Comment: Consider the fact that a new user only have a few hundred reputation, spending 1 reputation (even if it is only 1) feels more significant than a user with thousands of reps. I think the psychological effect is much stronger for low rep users here.

Comment: @nhahtdh: ...so don't downvote then

Comment: I think he's asking to cancel the -1 penalty when downvoting from within the review low quality posts.

Comment: if i down vote low quality post why i will lose point.

Comment: @raj: It's just one point. No need to get worked up about it.