# Why do downvotes cost reputation for the voter on Meta?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, meta

On main sites downvotes are usually used to show that answer is incorrect.
On meta sites downvotes [are used](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) to express agreement or disagreement.

On main sites downvotes cost reputation so that people downvote only posts that [really worth](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387/181366) it as it may give bad feelings to answerer.
But it can't be a reason on Meta as it's explicitly said that votes mean another thing here.

So why downvotes cost reputation on Meta?

Comment: Meta reputation is the absolutely most pointless metric on the Internet. Yes, it's even worse than the TIOBE index. Stop worrying about it.

Comment: @Yannis That's true until you accidentally get below 100 on here like me and you can't DV anymore...

Comment: I totally agree. I only downvote answers on Meta when I strongly disagree with them. The only times I downvoted answers on MSE were [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170939/349538) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77257/349538). There are a lot of answers that I disagree with (for example the answer to this question) that I didn't downvote because of the reputation cost. I also strongly disagree with [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53297/349538), but I didn't bother downvoting it because others have already done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That FAQ is generally considered to be referring to *questions*, not answers. We downvote questions to indicate we disagree with the ideas they imply or propose. For example, you're proposing a change to how meta.se should work, and I am going to downvote to indicate that I don't like the idea. Note that question votes do not cost reputation on any SE sites.

We don't *usually* downvote answers to indicate disagreement; contradictory answers can all be voted up on a discussion question, because there can be several valid points of view. But people will downvote my answer if they think it is factually *wrong*, and upvote it if what it says is factually correct; those are the same reasons for which answers are upvoted or downvoted on the main sites.

Comment: I've given and received a few downvotes on answers out of disagreement. I would go as far as saying that the only reason why most users seem to be reluctant to downvote answers they disagree with is the reputation loss. That doesn't stop them in some cases: [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33949), [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53297)

Comment: I would have downvoted this if it wouldn't have cost me reputation.