# Unable to answer a protected question in Beta

Tags: bug, protected-questions, beta-sites

There was a request in the Workplace Chatroom from a someone on Writers Beta to see if we could share some knowledge on a [question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6821/where-to-find-editors-to-hire-for-tech-blog). Myself not having used it before did not have an account so I created one and received the 100 rep association bonus. The question is protected so I would need to have at least 10 reputation to answer it but when I have gone to the question I am unable to answer it at all. There is no answer box...I double checked that you can use reputation gained from the [association bonus](https://writers.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) and there is nothing in there about not being able to.[image]

Comment: *"However, **the +100 account association bonus is ignored for this check**, so you must have earned 10 or more reputation on that specific site to answer a protected question."*

Comment: [Why is Association Bonus ignored when trying to answer a protected question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170937/why-is-association-bonus-ignored-when-trying-to-answer-a-protected-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to earn at least 10 reputation on that site.

> protected by Neil Fein♦ yesterday
>
> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam
>   answers by new users. **To answer it, you must have earned at least 10
>   reputation on this site**.