# Please add a link to the protected question faq post to the privilege page in help center

Tags: feature-request, help-center, protected-questions, meta-faq

So we have this great [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) post: [What is a “protected” or "highly active" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question)

Here is the entirety of the [help center page](//meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) of the privilege for protected questions:

> ###Protect Questions

> Privilege Type: Moderation Privilege
> Awarded At: 15,000 Reputation

> ###What are protected questions?

> A [protected question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-protected-question-status/) prevents answers being added by anonymous and very new users.

> Questions should be protected when they are garnering lots of views and newbies are adding "me too!", "thanks!" and possibly even spam non-answers.

> ###Which questions can be protected?

> Any question at least a day old can be protected and unprotected by users that have the privilege.

Notice the absence of the link to the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) post, which has a lot more information.

##[Please add this link.](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question)

Related (this is the problem I am trying to address): [Improve "Protected Question" message with regard to rep gained through Association Bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210481/improve-protected-question-message-with-regard-to-rep-gained-through-associati)

Comment: Problem is, the [tag:faq] posts are not 100% official and since low rep users can edit them any time (being CW), might even contain totally wrong information. Of course the long time users and/or SE staff do monitor most of those most of the time, mistakes might slip through and go unnoticed for long time. All in all, the [tag:faq] posts should link to the official Help Center sections, not the other way around.

Comment: @ShadowWizard In that case, one of two things that happen: 1. some of the correct information in the [tag:faq] post should be added to the help center. 2. The link should be added with a disclaimer. In this case, I had no idea the association bonus did not count towards protected questions until I dug around in meta questions, when that fact should be in the help center.

Comment: Well, they keep it short in the help center which is good. Adding too much details will make it wall of text that people will simply ignore. Since the page targets users with 15k rep anyway, it's unlikely that new users will get there for help about what is a protected question. Note it doesn't say anywhere "what is protected question" - for this, one will have to look in Meta, and indeed search simply for [protected question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=protected+question) brings the faq post as first result.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't know about you, but my instinct when I have a question about a site's feature, I go to the help center on that site, not MSE.

Comment: Well, it's a page that explains about the *privilege*, so it should focus on that. Bottom line and to sum this up, I'm not *against* what you suggest (hence no downvote as you might have noticed) however I'm also not supporting it, due to all the above. This doesn't mean it won't be done, at some point, just my own opinion.