# Does reputation propagate between main sites?

Tags: support, reputation

I'm a new user (long time lurker). I've noticed when I join a new main site to my account, I get a separate set of badges for that main site.

Does rep behave the same way or is it propagated between all my main sites?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does rep behave the same way or is it propagated between all my main sites?

Yes, rep behaves the same way; no, it doesn't propagate between main sites.

What *does* happen is the association bonus - when you reach +200 rep on one main site, you get a +100 rep bonus on all main sites.

See:

[What is the association bonus?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus)

Comment: While this is right, please be aware of [this (still standing) issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210481/311345) though.

Comment: @SimonKlaver That's not really an issue, but by design. And that's good so!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I believe the issue is that the _message_ isn't clear, not the feature itself.