# Change link "association bonus does not count" on Protected Question banner

Tags: feature-request, help-center, protected-questions

Recently the text of  Protected question note has been changed to include link "[the association bonus does not count](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user)".

> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam
>   answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10
>   reputation on this site ([the association bonus does not count](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user)).

I appreciate the change -it implemented  long time waiting feature request
[Improve "Protected Question" message with regard to rep gained through Association Bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210481/improve-protected-question-message-with-regard-to-rep-gained-through-associati/)
( should it be marked as completed?)

However the link is not useful. It points to 
[**Help Center > Privileges > Remove New User Restrictions**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user), which is confusing and seems irrelevant.
 The paragraph about Protected questions just repeat the message and doesn't have any new info.

It should point to [What is a “protected” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question?lq=1) 
or to a help page with an equivalent content.
Adding link to detailed explanation what are rules about  protected question is important to clarify any questions