# On Meta Stack Overflow, the association bonus should count towards the rep requirement for protected questions

Tags: feature-request, reputation, meta, protected-questions, association-bonus

The association bonus is [ignored by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170937/why-is-association-bonus-ignored-when-trying-to-answer-a-protected-question) for the 10 reputation requirement to answer a protected question.

Since Meta Stack Overflow is the only meta with separate reputation (correct me if I'm wrong), this has an annoying side effect: a "trusted" user from any of the network sites cannot answer protected questions here. For example, [this user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211084/167646) is unable to post in the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) while he has over 1500 reputation on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Meta.SO is... *special*. Why not make it more special?

Comment: The example you cite is a pretty specific edge case.  Does this problem have broader applicability?

Comment: @TheGrinch If [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/138642/protected-questions) is correct, there are currently 77 locked questions here. A quick scan didn't reveal any other problematic questions, so I guess you're right on it being an edge case.

Comment: I think this problem is larger and not only valid for meta.so: I currently have over 5000 rep on SO, active for over a year, but I'm not trusted enough to post an answer on Apple.StackExchange about a Mac problem. WTF?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be be resolved, now that the site split has happened and SO has its own normal-rules meta.

Comment: how so? The formatting sandbox is still here. Or is there one on every per site meta?

Comment: Well, that can be addressed by creating a sandbox on MSO, if there isn't one already. But the actual feature request — that the very special meta have different rules for protection specific to SO users — is moot since SO has a normal meta and MSE isn't associated with SO.

Comment: I didn't read that question as asking specifically for high rep SO users, but for established users on any SE site to be able to use this special meta. To quote from the question, *"a "trusted" user from any of the network sites "*

Comment: @KateGregory It appears that the team will unprotect the sandbox upon request.