# Update privilege page so it doesn't claim I can answer protected questions while I can't

Tags: bug, protected-questions, association-bonus, privileges-page

The [privilege page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) tells me I can answer protected questions, but I still can't answer protected questions on The Workplace. I know it is [because of the association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170937/245360) (also [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user)); I have more than 10 reputation but the association bonus does not count.

I propose that the new user restriction privilege page's check should factor in the association bonus.

Comment: @Catija You don't understand. On the priviledge page, it shows as earned. There's a check mark.

Comment: Do you see the part in that first answer where it says "*However, **the +100 account association bonus is ignored for this check**, so you must have earned 10 or more reputation on that specific site to answer a protected question.*"? You have not earned any rep on [Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/37680/james-lu?tab=reputation).

Comment: @Catija I'm saying the check should be more intelligent and check for it.

Comment: Edit your question to clarify what you're actually saying. Right now it reads like a dupe. If you want to request a feature that "answer protected questions should not be checked off on the priv page if you only have the association bonus"... that's completely different.

Comment: Obviously, you failed to read [the full page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) properly. It clearly says: "Note that one needs to earn 10 rep on the site to be able to answer a protected question. **The association bonus does not count**."

Comment: @Catija done that. If you have anything to add, please do.

Answer (score 15):

Indeed, you are very right. The privilege page is wrong actually. It only counts the reputation earned and doesn't include the check on earned reputation excluding association bonus.

> [image]

This is from my AskUbuntu privilege page. Yes, I can answer protected questions... But I can't. I haven't earned any reputation myself on that site.

I think the privilege page should be changed to make this clear. First, split the *Post more links* and *Answer protected questions* privilege. Then only check the *Answer protected questions* privilege when actually *all* requirements are met.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you've missed a line in the privilege description or got confused, once you run into a protected question, you're presented with such a notice:

> [image]

And all the misunderstandings immediately go away :)

(It is actually a recent addition)

Answer (score 2):

This is a definite problem, I came here to raise it.

With only association rep, or *specifically* not having 10 rep from other than associated rep, I cannot answer a protected question, but the privileges page states I can.

This is not the wording in the question status message, nor the main text in the privileges page, as both state "one needs to earn 10 rep on the site to be able to answer a protected question. The association bonus does not count."

The issue is the text to the right on the privileges page.

Images and *it did happen* right?

***Unix & Linux* - 101 associated rep only**

PRIVILEGES PAGE:
*James, you can answer protected questions:*
[image]

QUESTION STATUS:
*James, you can't answer protected questions:*
[image]

***Workplace* - 101 associated rep only**

PRIVILEGES PAGE:
*James, feel free to answer those protected questions, go on, you do it:*
[image]

QUESTION STATUS:
*James, what did we tell you last time? Fool you once shame on you, fool you twice and bwuhahaha!

strokes white cat evilly:*
[image]

---

It shows I can edit protected questions on my privileges earned page too:

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges
[image]