# I have enough rep to answer, but can't?

Tags: support, reputation, protected-questions

It says I need 10 rep to answer this question because of a spam lock, but I have 37 and cannot add my answer.

[High Sierra - The path /System/Installation/Packages/OSInstall.mpkg appears to be missing or damaged](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299808/high-sierra-the-path-system-installation-packages-osinstall-mpkg-appears-to-b/299977)

Furthermore, I made a rather larger bounty on another question and now I can't add comments to any questions. This seems like a rather unusual restriction, as I should never just "lose" that privilege that I earned a long time ago, there should be a cap on wagering away so much rep that I can't function anymore or contribute meaningfully, despite having a relatively trusted account.

Comment: You don't need any rep to answer, unless questions are mod locked to prevent that.

Comment: Have you clicked the question? It's locked by rep for spam reasons.

Comment: Are you sure you're not answer banned at that site?

Comment: @rene I think that https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231498/349538 is a better duplicate. Maybe you could add it to the duplicate list?

Comment: @DonaldDuck Done.

Answer (score 9):

This is a rather rare case; it would've made more sense for the protected question logic not to subtract the 100 association bonus because you've already 'spent' it with the bounty.

In any case, I've just removed the protection (which was applied automatically because there are four deleted answers by new users) and you're free to post your answer.

Answer (score 5):

The problem seems to be that since you got association bonus, the threshold is increased to 110. (In other words, you need to earn at least 10 reputation points *on the particular site* to be able to answer protected questions; even after deduction of the points you gave away in *bounties* and the points from the *association bonus*.)

For more details see:

- [Stack Exchange doesn't allow me to answer protected questions because I gave away earned rep in bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231498)
- [Why is the Association Bonus ignored when trying to answer a protected question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170937)
- [Improve “Protected Question” message with regard to rep gained through Association Bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210481)

Comment: Not relevant, the OP did earn 10 points, much more actually.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard I have edited the answer. Whether it is logical or not is another question, but from the linked posts, it seems that this is how the system is set up now.

Comment: No, OP has 37 points there. Reason they can't answer protected question is wrong logic being used. The system reduce 100 due to the association bonus, so it thinks the OP has -63 points.